# Error - Unhandled exception type Exception?

Tags: java, exception

I made a method which throws an Exception(). It causes an error - Unhandled exception type Exception

```
public void temp(){
  throw new Exception();
}
```

However, if I replace Exception with any other Exception such as NullPointerException, i don't get any error. Why is this happening ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Please tell me why you down voted me :-|

Comment: My guess is the downvoter thought that; checked vs unchecked exceptions is basic Java coding.  You should be able to search for the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the difference between a "checked" exception and an "unchecked" exception.  Anything that extends RuntimeException, including NullPointerException, are "unchecked" which means they don't need to be explicitly handled via a try/catch or by declaring that the method throw them.

Checked exceptions are those that do not extend RuntimeException and **must** be handled either by try/catch or by declaring your method throw it. So your code fails to compile because you are not handling it either way.

Comment: Thanks. Link with class hierarchy diagram at - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with a strange situation with this error. Namely, my Eclipse built the code without warnings, but for two of my colleagues compiler was giving this error. It took us a while to figure out, mainly because there is an easy remedy of using `RuntimeException`. But finally, the trick was that their Eclipse was set up for Java 1.6, while mine was tuned for 1.7.